# MS Access - Recordset not updateable

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables:

- A general sales table (has no primary key and links an order number to a material number)
- A general material table (Where the material number SHOULD be a primary key (it hasn't yet, I think I need to fix that)
- A reason for order table (the other 2 tables get their contents refreshed daily, so this needs to be a seperate table so the information is not lost)

I have a form which displays the order details and it has a subform in it that contains the material details. I want to have a drop down list in this subform for the reason of order table.

However, when I add the combo box and link it, I cannot actually enter or edit data into the field. I don't know whether this is because it wont also update the material and order number fields in the reason for order table.

Any advice or help?

Comment: If you don't have a primary key you can't update a record in a query that uses the table. You need what's called an 'updateable recordset.' A debugging step would be to open the query in the query editor, independent of the form, and try to edit a row.

Comment: In addition, every table should have a primary key (if not add one)! Usually you have a field called`id`wich autoincrements too.